# Embedded expressions not replaced if surrounded by characters

Tags: character, karate

The embedded expressions are not replaced when appended, prepended or surrounded by characters in the following simplified and very basic scenario:

```
* def jobId = '0001'
* def out = 
        """
        {
            "jobId": "#(jobId)",
            "outputMetadata": {
                "fileName_OK": "#(jobId)",
                "fileName_Fail_1": "some_text_#(jobId)",
                "fileName_Fail_2": "#(jobId)-and-some-more-text",
                "fileName_Fail_3": "prepend #(jobId) and append"
            }
        }
        """
* print out
```

Executing the scenario returns:

```
{
  "jobId": "0001",
  "outputMetadata": {
    "fileName_OK": "0001",
    "fileName_Fail_1": "some_text_#(jobId)",
    "fileName_Fail_2": "#(jobId)-and-some-more-text",
    "fileName_Fail_3": "prepend #(jobId) and append"
  }
}
```

Is it a feature, a limitation, or a bug? Or, did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as designed ! You can do this:

```
"fileName_Fail_2": "#(jobId + '-and-some-more-text')"
```

Any valid JS expression can be stuffed into an embedded expression, so this is not a limitation. And this works only within JSON string values or when the entire RHS is a string within quotes and keeps the parsing simple. Hope that helps !

Also refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Great! It helps! Thank you!